# Tensorflow variable batch size, variable reshape and weights

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to build a graph with variable batch size, variable reshape and variable weight shape. I'm using tensorflow 1.3.0.

Using the code below, **tf.get_variable** throws a **TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Tensor'**. **pool2** is defined somewhere else in the code.

```
# declare placeholder for variable batch size
images_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 64, 64, 1])
# code for 2 layers of convolution, normalization and max pooling
# reshape to perform, one matrix multiply
reshape = tf.reshape(pool2, [tf.shape(images_ph)[0], -1])
dim = tf.shape(reshape)[1]
var = tf.get_variable('name', [dim, 384], validate_shape=False)
```

I have also tried to substitute **dim** to have the 'correct' type as follows:

```
dim = reshape.get_shape()[1]
```

**dim** is equal to **None** and throws a **ValueError: Shape of a new variable (local3/xpto) must be fully defined, but instead was (?, 384).**

Comment: It looks like pool2 isn't defined.

Comment: pool2 is not defined in the code-snippet but is defined somewhere else in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for trying to help.

Given that I'm flattening the output of **pool2** to perform just one matmul, the solution is to explicitly compute the length of the second dimension of the reshape. This is computed on lines 1 and 2, where the **[1:]** offset on the first line comes from the variable batch size.

I could not use reshape with all dimensions being unspecified.

```
pool2_shapes = pool2.get_shape().as_list()[1:]
pool2_features_length = reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, pool2_shapes)
reshape = tf.reshape(pool2, [tf.shape(images)[0], pool2_features_length])
```

Comment: You can pass `-1` to any single dimension of the `reshape` to get 'the rest', so just use `pool2 = tf.reshape(pool2, (tf.shape(images)[0], -1))`

Comment: This does not work because tf.shape(images)[0] is None. It is exactly what I had in the question.

Comment: ah, in that case you can save yourself the effort of looking up the `None` shape, `tf.reshape(pool2, (-1, pool2_features_length))`. Not a big saving, but makes the code a bit more readable if you ask me.

Comment: Using -1 completely obscures where the shape size is coming from.

Comment: I disagree - it makes it clear it comes from the size of the tensor being reshaped and means exactly the same thing every time it's used in this context. It's mostly a style issue, so I accept there are differences of opinion.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to `get_variable` takes an integer or string, but as the error say, you've given it a tensor `[dim, 384]`.

See:  https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/get_variable

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've also tried this but it throws another error. I think this might be solvable if I use validate_shape as False.

Comment: Try something like 

`var = tf.get_variable('name', tf.shape(reshape))`

Comment: This will return an error because the type of tf.shape(reshape)[1] is tensor.

Comment: `tf.shape` returns the shape of a tensor, not a tensor.  See: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/shape

Comment: ok but the shape I want is not the shape of reshape but [None, 384].

Comment: The tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/shape says that tf.shape returns a tensor

Answer (score 0):

`tf.shape` returns a tensor, so *dim* in `[dim, 384]` is a Tensor; here is an int needed.

Try `dim = reshape.get_shape().as_list()[1]` # output is of int type

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've also tried this but it throws another error. Please check updated question.

Comment: You missed `as_list()`

Comment: Although as_list changes from Dimension to None type, it does not fix the problem.

Comment: Maybe we have different versions. `a=tf.constant([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])` and 
 `dim=a.get_shape()[1]` gives me as output **Dimension(3)** and `type(dim)` is not an int. But `dim=a.get_shape().as_list()[1]` has an output of **3** and `type(dim)` is int. For example, I have no problem with the variable `var=tf.get_variable('z', [a.get_shape().as_list()[1], 2])`.

Comment: your variable a is int and defined. my variable dim is None given that I do not know in advance what the dimension is.